# TeXmaker compiling problems (Windows 7)

Tags: compiling, texmaker

Good Morning, So i have been working with TeXmaker/Miktex in Windows 7 plataform for a while now, recently i updated TeXmaker 4.4.1 and then is when all the problems began.
So the problems are:

1. When I'm working with old documents which i already have build with the previous version of TeXmaker, the compiling of the document is done with out any output errors but when I check my pdf, ps or dvi none of the new changes i have made to the document are taken into account.
2. When I'm trying to make  build a new document it just keep telling me that the **"Log file can not been found"** (when I compile using PDFLatex) or i get the error message **"Could not star the command latex-interaction=nonstopmode%.tex"** (when I compile using Quick Build. Which is set to do latex+bib+latex(2)+dvips+ps2pdf+ view pdf)

So i know that the Log file error normally occur when MikTex is not install which it is, but I reinstalled any way and updated fully. Also already restart my computer. So any one have any suggestions what to do. Thx in advance

Comment: your editor clearly thinks tex is not installed, can you run tex outside the editor on the commandline? or see any other miktex utilities

Comment: Open a command line (outside from texmaker) and test if your texsystem is found with `pdflatex --version`. If this is successfull check the configuration in texmaker. Don't use "quick build" to locate the source of the problem, it involves to much applications.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by changing *all* the command lines in the options by the complete path.

Example: Replace

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

by

```
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

(with the quotation marks).

Comment: nope, it is not working.