# Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Tags: texmaker, windows

I read the post of [TeXmaker compiling problems (Windows 7)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226640/texmaker-compiling-problems-windows-7?newreg=3d5a687b29644fb5bea4abbea8fec939)
and the one answer that suggests to change all of the commands in the options with the suggested command. I have a question about that: Where is the commands option?
I am using Texmaker and Miktex, windows 7 64 bit. I downloaded a thesis template from this url: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis and extracted the zip in my latex templates folder in my TexMaker folder. But I too when I press Quick build I get the same error:

```
Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Could you please help me or suggest a link of a thesis template that would not have this problem for me?

note: I was able to be successful with latex CV templates.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MikTeX? The error indicate that TeXmaker cannot find LaTeX. What happens if you start a terminal (Windows menu -> Accessories -> Dos prompt) and you then run the command `pdflatex`?

Comment: Hi, I get "This is pdfTex, Version 3. 1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MikTex 2.9 64-bit). Should I have the MikTex in the same directory as the TexMaker?

Comment: If it works in the dos prompt out of the box, the it should work in Texmaker. Reading the last part of your post, is his only on a deficiency file that you get this error or can you compile a simple "hello world" document? (documentclass article, begin/end document, "hello world".

Comment: Plus what happens if you navigate in the dos prompt to the folder with the template and compile the template from the dos prompt? (hint: in Windows Explorer, if you right click on a folder *while holding down shift* you get extra options, among which "open prompt in this folder" or something like that)

Comment: Thanks. I can compile "hello world" and I have worked with a CV template before and it was fine. I will try your other suggestion and let you know. " if you navigate in the dos prompt to the folder with the template and compile the template from the dos prompt? "

Comment: Are there any news here?